# SQL Server 2008 Express connection problems

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm testing a C# application on SQL Server 2008. It used to work perfectly on 2005 Express edition, but now it seems to take ages to open connections to 2008 Express (default install, using sharedmem protocol).

Also, repeteadly I got errors of connection problems.

Any idea?

Comment: did you try to restart the instance and reboot the damn machine? :)

Comment: Several times, I'm afraid. The error is a connection getting lost or not error at all but queries taking forever to finish. It doesn't happen with the same DB on 2005.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any error message? What does it say exactly?

Any chance that this has something to do with the [default instance name problem](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958778/EN-US)?

Comment: I can connect, the app works, but from time to time some operations fail with a "can't connect to the server" (will find the exact message) error, like if it were running out of connections or something, but it's doing very little DB job.
First queries take ages (an insert and updated) compared to 2005, then later behaves correctly.

Comment: Is this on a local instance, or remote?

Answer (score 0):

Here is someone with the same problem:

http://sql-server-performance.com/Community/forums/p/28118/159186.aspx

Appears that there are problems with statistics on upgraded databases. They recommend droping and recreating the database statistics.